# How to make this python script memory efficient

Tags: python, django, gzip, data-dump, memory-optimization

This snippet pulls all of the docs out of my database, and dumps them into a gzip-compressed file. docs_to_dump is a django object containing all of the text documents to be dumped.

```
os.chdir(dump_dir)
filename = 'latest-' + court_id + '.xml.gz.part'
with myGzipFile(filename, mode='wb') as z_file:
    z_file.write('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\n<opinions dumpdate="' + str(date.today()) + '">\n')

    for doc in docs_to_dump:
        row = etree.Element("opinion",
            dateFiled           = str(doc.dateFiled),
            precedentialStatus  = doc.documentType,
            local_path          = str(doc.local_path),
            time_retrieved      = str(doc.time_retrieved),
            download_URL        = doc.download_URL,
            caseNumber          = doc.citation.caseNumber,
            caseNameShort       = doc.citation.caseNameShort,
            court               = doc.court.get_courtUUID_display(),
            sha1                = doc.documentSHA1,
            source              = doc.get_source_display(),
            id                  = str(doc.documentUUID),
        )
        if doc.documentHTML != '':
            row.text = doc.documentHTML
        else:
            row.text = doc.documentPlainText.translate(null_map)
        z_file.write('  ' + etree.tostring(row).encode('utf-8') + '\n')

    # Close things off
    z_file.write('</opinions>')
```

Unfortunately, it also consumes so much memory that the OS nukes it. I thought that by writing to a "File-like object", the compressed file would get made on the fly, and that memory would remain relatively low. Instead, it's taking up hundreds of MB, then crashing.

I'm not an expert on compression, but my impression is that the whole compressed file is getting stored in memory.

Is there a better way I ought to be doing this?

EDIT -- The whole file is here: https://bitbucket.org/mlissner/search-and-awareness-platform-courtlistener/src/2ca68efd8017/data-dumps/data-dumper.py

Comment: And how you retrieve `docs_to_dump`? Is it a database query to via `.objects.all()`?

Comment: It's nothing really. Just gives it support for with statement by giving it an __exit__ function.

Comment: @Torsten, sometimes yes. Othertimes, it's a filter on a field.

Comment: If you write to an uncompressed file, does it consume significantly less memory?

Comment: Then how many docs you got in your database (approximately).

Comment: I'm wondering if it even gets to the code shown.  It seems to me like building `docs_to_dump` is going to be the expensive part.  Are you sure you even get `docs_to_dump` created before running out of memory?

Comment: If your answer to andrewdski's question is no, have you tried setting `compresslevel` lower?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think andrewski might be right.  If you are crashing, try adjusting your Query's to use the [iterator](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#iterator) method

Something like.

```
docs_to_dump = Document.objects.all().order_by('court').iterator()
```

Should keep from loading your entire Queryset into memory.

Comment: +1  I suspected the same, which is why I asked earlier "If you write to an uncompressed file, does it consume significantly less memory?"  After seeing the docs for the iterator method, I think this is the most likely culprit.

Comment: Tried that. Made no difference, so I entered some print statements and did some profiling. The error occurred before compression, so I used the iterator code here, which worked: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1949/. Thanks for getting me in the right direction.